# what IC´s can duplicate an analog signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

currently i´m duplicating an analog signal with a dual buffer with op amps, i have to duplicate 8 signals... is there any IC that has IN, OUT1, OUT2?
[image: h]

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate the signals - can't you just connect the signal directly to the multiple destinations? If it is coming from a low impedance source you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any IC that has IN, OUT1, OUT2?

No, because each amplifier requires its own feedback circuit. Making individual op-amps is much more flexible. You can get quad op-amps in a single package so two of those would do for your application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7bDid.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A minimal solution.*

Your question doesn't explain why Figure 1 would not be suitable.

Comment: figure 1. is working fine, the thing is that it requires external wiring... I was hoping to find some ic which only has IN and OUT(1-2) pins

Comment: You're going to need external wiring anyway.

Comment: don´t understand your schematic, what exactly it´s doing

Comment: It it's just using one buffer and splitting the output 8 ways. Why do you need 8 individual buffers?

Comment: Why can't your signal A1 drive 8 loads?

Comment: I have 8 different signals

Comment: Your post says "*... is there any IC that has **IN**, OUT1, OUT2?*" (one input) and your schematic shows **one** input. Time to edit your question?